# Where are the uploaded files from redmine stored? and its not in "/redmine/files"

Tags: find, location, redmine

I am doing a migration from redmine 1.3.2 stable to 2.4.3 for that I need to migrate as well the uploaded files. In every documentation I can find it says that the uploaded files are in the `/installdirectory/files`

But for me, it's not the case! In fact I can't find any of the uploaded files using

```
locate filename
```

Uploaded file directory is selected as writeable in redmine, but I can't find it. Not even when I upload a testfile called 1234567.txt or something.

Any Ideas where it can be ?

MY installation folder contains this folder :

```
app, config, db, extra, lib, public, Rakefile, script, templates, test, vendor
```

any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it! It was somehow stored under `/var/lib/redmine/default/files/`

Funny that there is nothing else but this folder. There is a way to modify the folder location in the redmine installation.

For that you have to change under `redmine/config/xxxx.rb`  (your environment name)

and add: `attachments_storage_path: /your/file/location`